# Why should you not begin a sentence with numbers espressed using digits rather than words?

Tags: word-usage

For example,

> 120 cats are rescued.

is not usually considered as good style.

[Mayfield Electronic Handbook of Technical & Scientific Writing](https://www.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/numbers.htm):

> If you need to begin a sentence with a number, spell it out. It is better, however, to reword the sentence, if possible.
>
> - Thirty-two workstations were provided by the university. \
> - The university provided 32 workstations.

[Canadian Translation Bureau Writing Tips](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng):

> Spell out a number—or the word number—when it occurs at the beginning of a sentence, as well as any related numbers that closely follow it:

[Three Tips for Starting a Sentence with a Number](https://erinwrightwriting.com/starting-a-sentence-with-a-number/):

> - Spell Out Numbers at the Start of a Sentence.
> - Avoid Opening a Sentence with a Large Number.
> - Consult Your Style Guide before Starting a Sentence with a Number.
>
> Our four primary style guides (i.e., The Chicago Manual of Style, The Associated Press Stylebook, the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association, and the MLA Handbook from the Modern Language Association) all agree that numbers should normally be spelled out at the start of sentences.

Comment: You say it's usually not considered as good style, but what leads you to thinking that in the first place? Is this just your opinion, or did you read this somewhere? Does the fact you're asking this question mean you are doubting that?

Comment: @Smock Thank you for your comment. I have read this requirement in several publication style guides, and I thought that it is common that native speakers and advanced users is conscious of this fact - but in fact not. I will edit my question to clear the air. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

[This Grammar Monster article](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/numbers_starting_sentences.htm) advises that one should not start a sentenced with a number in figures, except possibly when it represents a year, but gives no reason except that doing so is "untidy", which does not seem much of a reason to me.

["Three Tips for Starting a Sentence with a Number"](https://erinwrightwriting.com/starting-a-sentence-with-a-number/) from Erin Wright give much the same advice, but says that:

> starting a sentence with a number can be confusing or disruptive for readers—doing so is generally grammatically acceptable if you follow the three guidelines outlined below

Those guidelines being to spell the number out, reword the sentence so the number is not at the start of the sentence, and to consult the relevant style guide. The article mentions that:

> Our four primary style guides (i.e., *The Chicago Manual of Style*, *The Associated Press Stylebook*, the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association*, and the *MLA Handbook* from the Modern Language Association) all agree that numbers should normally be spelled out at the start of sentences.

[This tip](https://style.mla.org/percentage-at-start-of-sentence/) from the MLA Style Center says:

> Since you should never begin a sentence with a numeral, you should first try to reword the sentence. If you find it unwieldy to reorder your words, spell out the number.

But it also give no particular reason for the rule.

["Can you start a sentence with a number?"](https://topcontent.com/for-writers/blog/can-you-start-a-sentence-with-a-number/) from TopContent advises:

> When writing, it is always important to be able to have a flowing and readable structure. One of the fastest and most noticeable ways to mess this up is by beginning a sentence incorrectly. Both new and experienced writers often struggle with what they can and cannot start a sentence with, often having been taught one thing and sticking to it.

The post goes on to recommend some of the same solutions, with some added specifics of not using a number at the start of a sentence, even spelled out, if it is followed by a unit of measure, includes a decimal point, is a percentage, or is a large number. The post also suggests consulting a style guide.

This suggestion of "flow" seems a bit more to the point to me.

Finally ["Seven (or 7?) Tips On Starting A Sentence With A Number"](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/seven-7-tips-starting-sentence-number-michael-blumfield) from Michael Blumfield, posting on LinkedIn, says:

> We’ve established structures for signaling to readers that we’ve reached the end of one sentence and we’re beginning another. This is so built in to our way of writing that we don’t think about it:
>
> - **Use a period** to say you’re done with one sentence.
> - **Put a space** – or in the old days, two spaces – between the period and the next sentence.
> - **Capitalize** the first letter of the word beginning the new sentence.
>
> Looked at that way, spelling out the number is the equivalent of that capital first letter. It’s a way of saying, “This is the beginning of a sentence.”
>
> Without the contrast between the word and numeric form, there's no way to indicate that shift. You could say that the period and space are enough, but if so, why not start sentences with a lowercase letter in the first word?

The post goes on to say that the rule is outdated, and in many cases can now be ignored.

I find this rationale -- that a digit cannot be capitalized and so makes the start of a sentence less clear, persuasive. I had long known and followed the rule, but with no clear idea why. This gives what seems to me a good reason for the rule, better than that for many rules of English usage.

We also see that there is wide and varied agreement on the basics of the rule, which is enough to make it clear that this is a customary part of English usage.